# Custom settings and parallel test execution

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I have a bunch of unit tests in which I'm updating my custom settings object to test certain workflows. This causes an `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` exception since multiple tests are updating the values simultaneously. If I choose 'Disable Parallel Running' in Options, I do not get any errors. I have the following questions with this approach:

- Custom objects have a setting to provide a `FOR_UPDATE` option for Locking. Is there a way I can update custom settings with a lock using `CustomSettings.getOrgDefaults()`?
- In case of installing the package, is there a way to specify 'disable parallel running'. If not, how would package installation work in this case as there would be test failures?

Comment: Tests always run in serial for deployment. About custom settings - got same issue, trying to do tests, that require custom settings modification, in single test method, one after one, and under runAs test user.

Comment: "Tests always run in serial for deployment" - I'm not sure if this is true. I'm deploying my code using mavensmate and the deployment validation fails because the tests are running in parallel.

Comment: @gerad26 yup, it is true. But validation tests may be run differently than actual deployments.

Comment: I see, is that the case only for production or sandbox as well? Also, is it right to say that parallel test execution is only useful for developer productivity and adds no value in actual deployments?

Comment: @SebastianKessel Do you have documentation for that?  I'm pretty sure they do in fact run in parallel.  I have noticed massive differences in times when running deployments with parallel testing turned off.  Also, I've run into the UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROWS errors during deployment directly.  Then again, I always validate then quick deploy, so it could be different between validation and pure deployment.  I don't see any good reason for that distinction though.

Comment: Here is the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm. Please note the yellow box: `Apex tests that run as part of a deployment always run synchronously and serially.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, this issue should have no impact on deployments. It can still be nice to have parallel testing work as you intend.

I have had some luck with a utility method structured essentially as follows:

```
public static void setupConfig()
{
    if (HierarchySetting__c.getOrgDefaults().Id != null && 0 < [SELECT count() FROM HierarchySetting__c])
    {
        system.assertNotEquals(null, HierarchySetting__c.getOrgDefaults().SomeField__c);
        return;
    }
    system.runAs(ADMIN_USER)
    {
        insert new HierarchySetting__c(SomeField__c='Populated');
    }
}
```